# Get Type object for generic type (no instance of the object exists)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a generic class `foo`.  I have a Type object called `bar`.

How do I get the Type `foo<bar>`?  I have seen examples of using a factory type setup when you have an instance of the object, but I don't have an instance.

Some code:

```
public class foo<T>
{

}

public Type GetGenericFoo(Type bar)
{
    Type genericFooBar = null;
    //work magic
    return genericFooBar;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
typeof(foo<>).MakeGenericType(bar)
```

so in you're code it will be like:

```
public Type GetGenericFoo(Type bar)
{
    return typeof(foo<>).MakeGenericType(bar);
}
```

Comment: It should be `typeof(foo<>)`.

Comment: `typeof(foo)` should be `typeof(foo<>)`